# Удаление чисел из строки

Tags: java, алгоритм

Дана строка String str и short переменная.
Подскажите, как удалить все цифры из строки, которые совпадают с цифрами в перемнной.

Comment: Приведите пример. Из вопроса не понятно. Если например у нас число `51` а строка `something1something5something6` должно ли в итоге получиться `somethingsomethingsomething6` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

способов много. например, можно написать такой метод:

```
public String removeNumber(final String str, final short sh) {
    final String strNumber = String.valueOf(sh);
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(""))
            .filter(s -> !s.equals(strNumber))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: А почему бы просто не сделать `replaceAll` и заменить sh на пустую строку?

Comment: @ First Sin я почему-то думал, что это своими руками надо написать, а не достать replaceAll из коробки... иначе в чем смысл вопроса?